# Trying to add last login date to customer grid. Not available in column selector

Tags: customer-grid, magento2.4.3

I am trying to add a last login date to the customer grid in the Admin Panel. The last login date is not present in the column selector in the customer grid. Can anyone advise?
Mage Version 2.4.3

Answer (score 1):

You can use below extension for your requirement.

https://github.com/lukepaoloni/magento2-module-customer-last-logged-in